# gatsby-source-filesystem not sourcing files from site directory when used in a theme

Tags: javascript, filesystems, gatsby, gatsby-theme

I'm trying to build a gatsby theme that uses `gatsby-source-filesystem` to source images.

I have set up a yarn workspace for development, my folder structure looks like this.

```
workspace/
├─ example.com/
│  ├─ src/
│  │  ├─ pages/
│  │  │  ├─ test.js
│  ├─ gatsby-config.js
│  ├─ package.json
├─ gatsby-theme-example/
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ images/
│  ├─ gatsby-config.js
│  ├─ gatsby-node.js
│  ├─ package.json
```

The yarn workspace is also set up correctly and the `gatsby-theme-example` is a dependency of it. `yarn workspaces info` correctly shows it in `workspaceDependencies`.

Both workspaces have a `gatsby-config.js` file, the `gatsby-theme-example` has the `gatsby-source-filesystem` in it.

```
{
   resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
   options: {
      name: `images`,
      path: path.join(__dirname, "images"),
   },
},
```

The problem I'm facing is that I have to put the images inside the theme directories image folder, otherwise they are not found by `gatsby-source-filesystem`. From following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkW06HK9-aY&t=161s) video and reading the [tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/building-a-theme/#add-static-data-to-a-theme), using `path.join` and the `__dirname` variable should point to the package that has the theme installed as a dependency, in my case `example.com`

Strangely, the `gatsby-plugin-page-creator` plugin in `gatsby-theme-example/gatsby-config.js` creates the pages defined in `example.com/src/pages` (the site directory) perfectly.

```
{
   resolve: "gatsby-plugin-page-creator",
   options: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "src/pages"),
   },
},
```

I also have `onPreBootstrap` defined in `gatsby-theme-example/gatsby-node.js` like this

```
exports.onPreBootstrap = ({ reporter }) => {
  const contentPath = `${__dirname}/images/`
  if (!fs.existsSync(contentPath)) {
    reporter.info(`creating the ${contentPath} directory`)
    fs.mkdirSync(contentPath)
  }
}
```

and it creates the images directory in `gatsby-theme-example` not `example.com`

I'm using `gatsby@4.18.0` and `gatsby-source-filesystem@4.18.0` and start the project using this command: `yarn workspace example.com start`

I've set up a [repo](https://github.com/AlexanderProd/gatsby-source-filesystem-theme-bug), which you can use to reproduce the issue like this:

1. `git clone https://github.com/AlexanderProd/gatsby-source-filesystem-theme-bug`
2. `yarn workspace example.com install`
3. `yarn workspace example.com start`
4. go to http://localhost:8000/___graphql
5. run the following query

```
query MyQuery {
  allFile {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution and in this case the optimal one is to just use `images` as a path.

```
{
   resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
   options: {
      name: `images`,
      path: `images`,
   },
},
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/36103#discussioncomment-3126133) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is supposed to be done that way but I found a workaround.

In the sites `gatsby-config.js` (`example.com/gatsby-config.js`) where the theme is specified, I added an option for the images path.

```
{
   resolve: `gatsby-theme-example`,
   options: {
      imagesPath: path.join(__dirname, "images"),
   },
},
```

and then in the themes `gatsby-config.js` I'm using the option value.

```
module.exports = options => ({
   plugins: [
      {
         resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
         options: {
            name: `images`,
            path: options.imagesPath,
         },
      },
   ]
})
```